# Combine all assertion results and send it over as the body of SMTP sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to combine all my assertion results and send it over as the body of my SMTP sampler in Jmeter. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally JMeter stores all the assertion results in the .jtl results file so when you [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
```

Your `result.csv` file should have `failureMessage` column containing all the assertions failures details

[image]

if it doesn't - make sure to add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config):

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
```

---

Alternative solution (though I wouldn't recommend it) would be collecting the interim assertion failures into the relevant JMeter Property like:

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your main Thread Group at the same level as your Samplers (or according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide))
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def assertionResults = props.get('assertionResults')
   def resultBuilder = new StringBuilder()
   if (assertionResults == null) {
       props.put('assertionResults', '')
   }
   else {
       resultBuilder.append(assertionResults)
   }

   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
           resultBuilder.append(assertionResult.getFailureMessage()).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
       }
   }
   props.put('assertionResults', resultBuilder.toString())
   ```
3. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
4. Refer the aggregate assertions information using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(assertionResults,)}` where required, i.e. in "Message" body:

   [image]

Comment: Hello Dmitri, please refer to my answer below. I cannot paste picture here

Answer (score 0):

I have the following result based on my assertion:

[email result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwIJg.png)

Would it be possible to remove the null or it is more ok if I could have the email body same with the Assertion Results
[assertion result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i50V6.png)